# Can edge loops be aligned equidistant?

Tags: modeling

In a situation where many gaps need to be aligned I wonder whether there is some function (or addon) which allows to align two edge loops equidistant or edge by edge in parallel?

The image below has a green line and the vertices opposite each other (y-axis) should have the same distance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After double tapping <kbd>G</kbd> with an edge-ring selected, you enter *[edge-slide mode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Edges)* now press <kbd>E</kbd> to access a model operator that attempts to align the edge-ring with either of the neighboring edge-rings.  You can choose which parallel ring to align with by pressing the <kbd>F</kbd> key.

Note that that the header also shows the keys:

[image]

[image]

The same thing works for Loop Cut and Slide <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, the only problem this function is that it works best for meshes that are uniform along all three axis.  If the object is really long along one axis; the edge-align tool will behave as if the Object has non-uniform scale even if it does not.

Comment: @MarcClintDion I hope that my edit is OK for you. Thanks for this excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

- Use **Bridge Edge Loops** tool to merge/collapse them.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> to make an even rip fill.

[image]